# AppVeyor custom (deployment) script - what is the difference between PS, PS CORE, CMD and SH in yaml file?

Tags: deployment, yaml, settings, appveyor

I am just trying to deploy my backend from Github to Azure using AppVeyor.
Now I got a bit stuck at figuring out how the deployment script (that I put into the yaml file) should look like.

I found something like this:

```
curl -X POST -u myNick --data-binary @"myApiArtefact.Api.zip" https://my-azure-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

And I put it into **Settings > Deployment > Script** colon in AppVeyor.

But I can also set if it is PS, PS CORE, CMD or SH script, which changes the prefix of the script (with for example -sh rest-of-the-script).
I guess that could mean that the script is executed via powershell, command line or bash.
But for a Windows-more-like-frontend-lady, It's all Greek to me. I don't know what it changes? What happens when this script is run, please?

Answer (score 2):

These script settings are explained in the [AppVeyor documentation on Build Configuration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#script-blocks-in-build-configuration). Basically they influence how the line (or block) are executed:

- PS (`ps`) uses PowerShell (on Ubuntu it is the [same](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/getting-started-with-appveyor-for-linux/#running-windows-and-linux-builds-side-by-side) as PS Core).
- PS Core (`pwsh`) uses PowerShell core. Same syntax as PowerShell, but it also works on Linux (AppVeyor has an Ubuntu image available).
- CMD (`cmd` or no prefix on Windows) uses `cmd.exe`.
- SH (`sh` or no prefix on Linux) uses Bash and will be executed on Linux only.

For your `curl` command I would recommend using the `cmd` (Windows) or `sh` (Linux) and not either PowerShell variant since the `@` character has a special meaning. When executed, it will try to upload a zip file to the website using a certain username.

For yet another AppVeyor-specific approach, have a look at their documentation on [Publishing to Azure App Service with Zip Push Deploy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/azure-app-service-zip-push-deploy/).

Comment: No prefix runs `cmd` on Windows and `bash` on Linux. [This part of doc](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/getting-started-with-appveyor-for-linux/#running-windows-and-linux-builds-side-by-side) will shed some light too.